# C# - NetworkStream Error - "The operation is not allowed on non-stream oriented sockets."

Tags: c#, sockets, networkstream

I am trying to connect to a socket and then Read a NetworkStream.

My code is below:

```
NetworkStream myNetworkStream;
Socket socket;

socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IPv4);

socket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("8.8.8.8"), 8888);

myNetworkStream = new NetworkStream(socket);

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int offset = 0;
int count = 1024;

myNetworkStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
```

When I try to debug the above I get the following error:

> The operation is not allowed on non-stream oriented sockets.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `SocketType.Stream` in lieu of `SocketType.Raw`.

Comment: Tried that, got this error: "The requested protocol has not been configured into the system, or no implementation for it exists"

Comment: I believe you're attempting to connect to a UDP socket and not a TCP socket.  Search for that error message here and it specifies SOCK_DGRAM.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use this it will work "Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Unspecified)"